# Filter related field Django orm shows multiple invalid results

Tags: django, django-orm

**Query**

```
TechnicianAssignment.objects.filter(Q(slot__slot_date=curr_datetime.date())&Q(assigned_technician__attendance_Technician__attendance_status__in=['Rejected', 'Absent', 'Someone else reported', 'Present']))
```

Models in short:

```
**Table 1**:
class TechnicianTeam(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
supervisor = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name="TechnicianSupervisor", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
customer_profile = models.ForeignKey('login.CustomerProfile',
                                    related_name="technician_TeamUser", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class Meta:
    db_table = "technician_team"


**Table2:**
class TechnicianAssignment(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slot = models.ForeignKey('technician_management.TechnicianSlot',
                                        related_name="assignment_Slot", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    assigned_technician = models.ForeignKey('technician_management.TechnicianTeam',
                                        related_name="assignment_Technician", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "technician_assignment"
**Table3**
ATTENDANCE_CHOICES = [
    ('Rejected','Rejected'),
    ('Someone else reported','Someone else reported'),
    ('Absent','Absent'),
    ('Present','Present')
]
    class TechnicianAttendance(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        technician = models.ForeignKey('technician_management.TechnicianTeam',
                                        related_name="attendance_Technician", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        slot = models.ForeignKey('technician_management.TechnicianSlot',
                                            related_name="attendance_Slot", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        attendance_status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=ATTENDANCE_CHOICES, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "technician_attendance"
```

Question what is wrong with my query:

I need to filter out from TechnicianAssignment where in entries were "slot__slot_date" is current date and "__attendance_Technician__attendance_status__in" = ['Rejected', 'Absent', 'Someone else reported', 'Present']

there is only 1 entry in db with attendance status 'Present' but i am getting many output because of "__attendance_Technician__attendance_status__in" this filter.

Comment: Does adding `.distinct()` to your queryset remove the duplicates?

Comment: @IainShelvington no because it taking 1 entry for each status. It should only be 1 as in db there is only entry with status "pending".

Comment: @IainShelvington it shows 4 entry with distinct means 1 for each attendance status.There are many attendance entries for releted technician but only 1 with slot_date as current date.